# Combine two names() of lists in R

Tags: r, list, append, names

I am trying to append extra dataframes to a list of dataframes and also update the names() of the lists:

```
DE_list = list(imagetag_age_backup, imagetag_emotion_backup, imagetag_facial_backup, imagetag_gender_backup)
names(DE_list) = c("imagetag_age_backup", "imagetag_emotion_backup", "imagetag_facial_backup", "imagetag_gender_backup")

names(df_list) <- append(names(df_list), names(DE_list))
df_list <- append(df_list, DE_list)
```

However I get this  error:

```
Error in names(df_list) <- c(names(df_list), names(DE_list)) : 
  'names' attribute [30] must be the same length as the vector [26]
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to append the list first

Comment: I tried that and I still get the error : Error in names(df_list) <- append(names(df_list), names(DE_list)) : 
  'names' attribute [34] must be the same length as the vector [30]

Comment: Create a new object i.e. `df_new <- append(df_list, DE_list)`

Comment: Get both lists named first (with one name per item--you can't have more names than items), then append them with `c(df_list, DE_list)`